# How to select records without duplicate on just one field and duplicate field total in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+  
| id     |        category   | price |  
+------------+---------------+-------+  
   1         | Home          | 20
   2         | Transport     | 30
   3         | General       | 40
   4         | General       | 50
```

My desired result is something like this:

```
   category            price
+------------+---------------+-------+  
    Home              20
    Transport         30  
    General           90
```

I need to have category  names without any duplicate. Actually I need their id and category , What is the best SQL command to make this? I used DISTINCT in the form below but I could not achieve an appropriate result.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(id) AS id, `categories`, `expenses_price`
FROM
    expensess
WHERE
    SUM(expenses_price)
GROUP BY `categories`
```

but total not calculate

Comment: mysql code in php sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the min id and sum of prices:

```
SELECT 
 min(id) as ID, category, SUM(price) 
FROM
 expenses

GROUP BY category
ORDER by ID
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69a924/1)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple `group by`

```
SELECT 
    min(id) id, `categories`, SUM(price) `expenses_price`
FROM
    expensess
GROUP BY `categories`
```

Comment: but the expenses_price not calculate